# glibtool on MacBook

Tags: xcode, macos, libtool

I am building a project on Mac. It ends with

```
glibtoolize: command not found.
```

I don't find any instructions for installing glibtool and glibtoolize. All search results talks about installing libtool, which I already installed on my Mac.

Anyone know how this works? (I already installed the lated xcode, but no glibtool in my system.)

Answer (score 8):

Install Homebrew (http://brew.sh). And then I guess `brew install libtool`.

Comment: So try `which glibtoolize`. If there is no result it isn't installed correctly. If there is, your project does not seem to look at the correct location for glibtoolize.